# Can we say that by synchronizing a block of code we are making the contained statements atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I want to clear my understanding that if I surround a block of code with `synchronized(this){}` statement, does this mean that I am making those statements atomic?

Comment: statement i = i + 1 can be affected by other thread execution if not properly syncronized

Comment: @assylias - I agree.. I apologize :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not ensure your statements are atomic. For example, if you have two statements inside one synchronized block, the first may succeed, but the second may fail. Hence, the result is not "all or nothing". But regarding multiple threads, you ensure that no statement of two threads are interleaved. In other words: all statements of all threads are strictly serialized, even so, there is no guarantee, that all or none statements of a thread gets executed.

Have a look at how [Atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity) is defined.

Here is an example showing that the reader is able to ready a corrupted state. Hence the synchronized block was not executed atomically (forgive me the nasty formatting):

```
public class Example {

    public static void sleep() {
        try { Thread.sleep(400); } catch (InterruptedException e) {};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Example example = new Example(1);
        ExecutorService executor = newFixedThreadPool(2);
        try {
            Future<?> reader = executor.submit(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
                int value; do {
                    value = example.getSingleElement();
                    System.out.println("single value is: " + value);
                } while (value != 10);
            }});
            Future<?> writer = executor.submit(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
                for (int value = 2; value < 10; value++) example.failDoingAtomic(value);
            }});
            reader.get(); writer.get();
        } catch (Exception e) { e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        } finally { executor.shutdown(); }
    }

    private final Set<Integer> singleElementSet;

    public Example(int singleIntValue) {
        singleElementSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(singleIntValue));
    }

    public synchronized void failDoingAtomic(int replacement) {
        singleElementSet.clear();
        if (new Random().nextBoolean()) sleep();
        else throw new RuntimeException("I failed badly before adding the new value :-(");
        singleElementSet.add(replacement);
    }

    public int getSingleElement() {
        return singleElementSet.iterator().next();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok....i think i get your point.....plz correct me if i am wrong.....in a synchronized block which has two statements it is quite possible that after executing the first one, the thread goes to sleep(pulled from running to runnable by jvm) leaving the second one un-executed until it wakes up(runnable to running).....so that way even if I have used synchronised.....the block is still not atomic !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: No. The scenario is slightly different and I will update my answer providing some source code, showing why a synchronized block is not atomic. Should be in my answer in a minute.

Comment: @Sumit Pal Singh: sleeping does not release the lock associated with a `synchronized` block. Only if your code calls `wait` on the same object you have synchronized on, the lock is released for the waiting time.

Comment: I don't want to release the lock. I sleep to keep it and to show that accessing the value hold in the `Set` is possible before the second statement is executed. This is evidence enough to prove synchronized blocks are not atomic.

Answer (score 3):

No, synchronization and atomicity are two different concepts.

Synchronization means that a code block can be executed by at most one thread at a time, but other threads (that execute some other code that uses the same data) can see intermediate results produced inside the "synchronized" block.

Atomicity means that other threads do not see intermediate results - they see either the initial or the final state of the data affected by the atomic operation.

Comment: You are wrong on Atomicity. What you describe is [Isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation). Consider a method which is synchronized on its class, and modifies a field. But the getter is not synchronized an hence, may read the field. Isolation is not guaranteed this way.

Comment: No, what i describe is [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity). Atomicity is whether you can see intermediate results from a single operation. Isolation is about multiple concurrent operations and whether the overall result is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that java uses `synchronized` as a keyword.  A `synchronized` block in Java is a "mutex" (short for "mutual exclusion").  It's a mechanism that insures only one thread at a time can enter the block.

Mutexes are just one of many tools that are used to achieve "synchronization" in a multi-threaded program:  Broadly speaking, synchronization refers to all of the techniques that are used to insure that the threads will work in a coordinated fashion to achieve a desired outcome.

Atomicity is what Oleg Estekhin said, above.  We usually hear about it in the context of "transactions."  Mutual exclusion (i.e., Java's `synchronized`) guarantees something less than atomicity:  Namely, it protects *invariants*.

An invariant is any assertion about the program's state that is supposed to be "always" true.  E.g., in a game where players exchange virtual coins, the total number of coins in the game might be an invariant.  But it's often impossible to advance the state of the program without temporarily breaking the invariant.  The purpose of mutexes is to insure that only one thread---the one that is doing the work---can see the temporary "broken" state.

Answer (score 0):

For code that use syncronized on that object - yes.

For code, that don't use syncronized keyword for that object - no.

Comment: This answer does not deserve a down vote.  It may be far from comprehensive, but it speaks to an important point that nobody else has mentioned:  Only one thread at a time can enter a block that is synchronized on a unique, static object, but so what?  The point of using synchronized blocks is to guarantee certain invariants in the program's data.  That only works if _EVERY_ block of code that can break the invariant is synchronized.

Comment: suppose i synchronize on that object.....i guess, the thread could still go to sleep (running to runnable).....if yes, then how is the block still atomic ??                                                      Also will the changes of the statements that have executed in that block be reflect to the outer world ??

Answer (score 0):

> Can we say that by synchronizing a block of code we are making the contained statements atomic?

You are taking a very big leap there. Atomicity means that the operation if atomic will complete in one CPU cycle or equivalent to one CPU cycle whereas Synchronizing a block means only one thread can access the critical region. It may take multiple CPU cycles for processing code in the critical region(which will make it non atomic).